# how to read csvfile into dictionary format

Tags: python

I have a csv file as below:

```
a,green
a,red
a,blue
b,white
b,black
b,brown
```

I want to read it into python dictionary as below

```
{'a':{'green','red','blue'},'b':{'white','black','brown'}}
```

How can I do? Help me please

Comment: This seems like a pretty straight forward application of `csv` and `collections.defaultdict`.  Is there anything in particular that you're having trouble with?  Can you show us the code that is giving you trouble so we can tailor our advice to help guide your understanding instead of just giving you some code?

Comment: you'll maybe need :
https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html
and then do a loop to append your dictionary. Then post some code please !

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you want a dict with a list of values per key

`{'a':['green','red','blue'],'b':['white','black','brown']}`

If so, a possible quick workaround could be something like this

```
import csv

# Get a all the rows in the format [[k, v], ...]
rows = list(csv.reader(open('file_path_here', 'r')))
# Get all the unique keys
keys = set(r[0] for r in rows)

# Get a list of values for the given key
def get_values_list(key, _rows):
    return [r[1] for r in _rows if r[0] == key]

# Generate the dict
keys_dict = dict((k, get_values_list(k, rows)) for k in keys)

print keys_dict
```

But I'm pretty sure this solution has a lot of room for improvement if you spend some time on it.